# cocos2d-x: loading sprite from another thread not possible, any pattern?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, cocos2d-x

**Facts of my program**

1. Cocos2d-x main loop runs in its own thread.  Let's call it *cocos2d-x-thread*.
2. I have a `task_scheduler` that runs in its own thread, in which you can submit lightweight tasks. Let's call it *task_scheduler-thread*.
3. Every x milliseconds, a callback is emitted from the `task_scheduler` thread.  Let's call it *task_scheduler-tick-callback*.

**What I want to do**

I want to load a sprite when *task_scheduler-tick-callback* is emitted, but I cannot do it from that thread, so I will have to submit some kind of *work* to be performed by *cocos2d-x thread*.

**Problem**

1. How can I make *cocos2d-x-thread*, when receiving this *work*, to be executed? Because cocos2d-x is already running its own loop and **I want to avoid injecting custom code to the cocos2d-x generated project at all costs**.

Any patterns?

EDIT: Idea -> any callback function called for each loop iteration in cocos2d-x? Does that exist? I could integrate the call to my *work* piece like that.

Comment: search for thread synchronization, and keep in mind that cocos2d itself is not thread safe

Comment: well, I know about thread synchronization enough I guess. My main problem is to make cocos-2d-x-thread to call my submitted work piece without touching adding or removing code on that side. I think there should be a callback.

Comment: why not schedule an update selector (method), for example on the scene, and run your thread from that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this to execute your code in main thread:

```
Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->performFunctionInCocosThread([]{
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and propably not the most elegant) way to achieve this is to have a kind of buffer (i.e. an `std::list`) and a method that would periodically check if there is new data in the buffer. In cocos such a function is an `void update(float dt)` on every `(CC)Scene` which is run between each frame, or you could as well schedule your own with desired time interval.

Of course reading and writing to the buffer need to be done in critical sections.